# jquery click function with ajax content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My End goal is to have ajax displayed content be clickable to shove whatever it's value is into a text box.

Right now I have the ajax loading but when I click on it, it doesn't work. As of now I have jquery assigned the 'a' tag so when it's clicked it puts the static text "works" in the textarea with the id=email-body.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Expand Panel
    $('a').click(function(){ 
        $('#email-body').val($('#email-body').val()+'works');
    }); 

});
```

This works just fine for a tags that aren't part of the ajax content but it doesn't work for the ajax content. Is there a special pull system I should use to have jquery effect ajax content?

Also static text and clicking on an a tag isn't really want I want.

Right now my ajax is doing the following:

```
foreach($search_found as $search_row){
    $hint=$hint . '<a>'.ucwords($search_row['email_module_name']).'</a>';
}
echo $hint;
```

Is there a way I can have it be:

AJAX:

```
<div class="module" value="'.ucwords($search_row['email_module_name']).'">
     '.ucwords($search_row['email_module_name']).'
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Expand Panel
    $('.module').click(function(){ 
        $('#email-body').val($('#email-body').val()+'$this->value');
    }); 

});
```

Comment: It would be a good joke to post a duplicate link...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('.module').live('click', function(){ 
    $('#email-body').val($('#email-body').val()+'$this->value');
});
```

I figured it out and came back on to see someone posted .on

I tried this and it did not work. What did work was .live

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Then [`$(document).on("click", ".module", function(){ ... });`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14446944/417685) should work!

Comment: I'm downvoting, this is definitely a discouraged answer while using jQuery 1.7+

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$('div').on('click', '.module', function(){ 
    $('#email-body').val($('#email-body').val()+'$this->value');
});
```

This allows the 'click' function to attach to the elements that are brought in via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind an event to current and future elements.

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(){ 
    $('#email-body').val($('#email-body').val()+'works');
});
```

Or,

```
$(document).on("click", ".module", function(){
  $('#email-body').val($('#email-body').val()+'$this->value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to delegate the events, to do this you can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Expand Panel
    $(documnet).on('click', 'a', function(){ 
        $('#email-body').val($('#email-body').val()+'works');
    }); 

});
```